# Django cannot redict some of urls with uwsgi

Tags: django, url, uwsgi

In project/urls.py which is the root urls.py .

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^webadmin/', include('webadmin.urls')), # With templates and plain text for returning.
    url(r'^api/', include('restAPI.urls')), # Without templates. Only plain text for returning.
]
```

In webadmin/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^api/search/', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^api/delProject/', views.delProject, name='delProject'),
    url(r'^api/addProject/', views.addProject, name='addProject'),
    url(r'^api/statistics/', views.statistics, name='statistics'),

    url(r'^(?P<action>(users|login|statistics|projects))/', views.index, name='webadmin'),
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

All the url in restAPI are working correctly.

But in `webadmin`, all the url are redict to `views.index`.

For example, when I goto `http://example.com/webadmin/api/login/`, it will show `http://example.com/webadmin/`.

If I remove the last line `url(r'^', views.index, name='index')`, there is nothing changed.

If I use `python3 manage.py runserver`, it has rigth result.

My uwsgi ini is:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/var/www/project
wsgi-file=/var/www/project/project/wsgi.py
static-map = /static/=/var/www/project/static/
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/project.log
http = :8000
vacuum = true
master = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add end of the line anchor `$`

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```